# c# 6 Primary ctor

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have the following two classes

```
public class Point(int x, int y)
    {
        public int X { get; } = x;
        public int Y { get; } = y;
    }



    public class Point2
    {
        public int X { get; private set; }
        public int Y { get; private set; }

        public Point2(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }
```

and using jetbrains dotpeek i get the following when decompile:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Point
  {
    public int X
    {
      get
      {
        return this.\u003CX\u003Ek__BackingField;
      }
    }

    public int Y
    {
      get
      {
        return this.\u003CY\u003Ek__BackingField;
      }
    }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Point2
  {
    public int X { get; private set; }

    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Point2(int x, int y)
    {
      this.X = x;
      this.Y = y;
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot understand for Point class using Primary constructor that the ctor when decompiled is empty. Thought it would be the same as Point2 where it would set the backing fields. 
Can someone explain this?

Comment: See [this](http://thomasardal.com/primary-constructors-in-c-6-0/) for proper decompiled code.

Comment: It is the default constructor, every C# class without an explicit constructor has one.  Auto-generated by the C# compiler.  Your decompiler doesn't show why this is necessary, it omits `: base()`.  Necessary to ensure that the base constructor runs as well.  The System.Object constructor in your case.  Using ildasm.exe can give you more insight, it hides less.

Comment: @GrantWinney yes - better go C# light http://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/c-light ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you don't see this is because the code that initializes backing fields in generated by the compiler and by default dotPeek doesn't show compiler-generated code. But if you enable "Show compiler-generated code" you will see the following:

```
public class Point
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly int \u003CX\u003Ek__BackingField;
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly int \u003CY\u003Ek__BackingField;

    public int X
    {
      get
      {
        return this.\u003CX\u003Ek__BackingField;
      }
    }

    public int Y
    {
      get
      {
        return this.\u003CY\u003Ek__BackingField;
      }
    }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
      this.\u003CX\u003Ek__BackingField = x;
      this.\u003CY\u003Ek__BackingField = y;
      base.\u002Ector();
    }
}
```